# nodejs How to get gmail raw messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api

I am trying to get the full email message data with body content using the raw option of the format as described in the [gmail api reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get). How ever it doesn't seem to work. Below is my code:

```
function listMessages(auth) {
  var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  var nextPageToken = null;

  gmail.users.messages.list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    pageToken: nextPageToken,
    q: ''
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }

    var msgs = response.messages;
    if (msgs.length == 0) {
      console.log('No messages found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Messages:');
      the_format = 'raw';
      for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        var msg = msgs[i];
        console.log('- %s', msg.id);
        gmail.users.messages.get({
          auth: auth,
          userId: 'me',
          id: msg.id,
          format: the_format,
        }, function(err, response) {
          if (err) {
             console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
             return;
          }

          console.log(response);

        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And here is an example of a returned result. I don't see the raw fields and the same result is always returned when I change the 'format' (raw or minimal).

What am I missing here ?

```js
{ id: '16xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  threadId: '161xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  labelIds: [ 'UNREAD', 'Label_44', 'CATEGORY_UPDATES' ],
  snippet: 'atom posted: &quot;Voici le 9e volet de notre rubrique À quoi tu joues ? Aujourd&#39;hui la Testing Team vous embarque au Japon, avec Sakura. S&#39;est perdu dans un manoir infernal, ou a défendu un',
  historyId: '11336356',
  internalDate: '1516xxxxxxxxx',
  payload:
   { partId: '',
     mimeType: 'multipart/alternative',
     filename: '',
     headers:
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ],
     body: { size: 0 },
     parts: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  sizeEstimate: 98391 }
```

Comment: Does it work for you in the API Explorer in that link you included in your question? You might have to give the format in lower case, i.e. `raw`.

Comment: I suggest going over to [Users.messages.get Try-it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it) to test what you're trying to do. Provide the userId and the id then there's a 'format' parameter where you have the option to use full, metadata, minimal, and raw.

Comment: My mistake, I've tried both 'raw' and 'RAW' as well as 'minimal' or other options and no options are changing the results. I always get the same 'full' message. I have also tried with the API explorer and it works. I would like the raw message formatted like and email to reimport it easily. The python api package works also perfectly. Is there a bug with the nodejs one or do I pass the format option wrongly ?

Comment: Do you have any way of logging the outgoing request? Your question and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547531/no-label-add-or-removes-specified-on-gmails-node-js-api) indicates that there might be a bug in the Nodejs library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
var msgs = response.data.messages;
```

instead of:

```
var msgs = response.messages;
```

That's it.