# node.js gmail api ignoring query string

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I am using the gmail api for node.js as follows:

```
gmail.users.messages.list({auth: oauth2Client, userId:'me', q: 'from: Jon.Doe@gmail.com',}, (err, response) => { console.log(response)};
```

The query string is being ignored and I am getting my entire inbox of message id's back.

The query string works as expected when using the gmail api explorer.

I am using the 'https://mail.google.com/' scope.

Any thoughts on what the issue may be?

Best,
Patrick

Comment: Do you have any way of logging the outgoing request? Your question, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547531/no-label-add-or-removes-specified-on-gmails-node-js-api), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525620/nodejs-how-to-get-gmail-raw-messages) indicates that there might be a bug with the nodejs library.